# Disciplined badge

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

I've seen some topics about 'Disciplined badge` but couldn't find the answer to the following question:

is it a bug or a feature that you receive the badge after deleting the answer and do not lose it after undeleting it?

Answer (score 0):

From [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/312043)

> Regular badges, however, once earned, are yours to keep. Even if the criteria by which you earned a badge have changed (the post was deleted, you got downvoted, etc.) you get to keep your badge. If you qualify for the same badge again (another post earns you a post-related badge, for example), you won't be penalized either.

So this is a feature, and you won't lose the `Disciplined` badge once you earned.